# Cuda library dead after linux-updates

Tags: cuda, tensorflow

System ran beautifully, until I received update notifications from Ubuntu. So I accepted. And after they ran I get a big Cuda-issue:

```
('fp: ', <open file '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so', mode 'rb' at 0x7f8af1a63300>)
('pathname: ', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so')
('description: ', ('.so', 'rb', 3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "translate.py", line 41, in <module>
    import tensorflow.python.platform
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 31, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 27, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any idea?
thx

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming question and have voted to close it as off-topic.

Comment: @talonmies isn't it a configuration related question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your system cannot find "libcudart.so.7.5".

```
libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Could you check this file exist and you set the PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly?

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Understood this was the wrong place to open the question. Want to close it nevertheless:
I, being a linux-rook, always ran my python scripts with a sudo in front. After the update the users got somehow mixed up. So the sudo-user looked at different paths suddenly. Running the scripts without sudo did the trick.

Comment: @friesel: Perhaps make that an answer.